# How does SWI Prolog handle lists under the hood?

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

Why is this not working?

```
?- '.'(a,[]).
ERROR: Unknown procedure: ('.')/2
ERROR:     However, there are definitions for:
ERROR:         ('.')/3
false.

?- .(a,[]).
ERROR: Unknown procedure: ('.')/2
ERROR:     However, there are definitions for:
ERROR:         ('.')/3
false.

?- .(a,[]) == [a].
ERROR: Type error: `dict' expected, found `a' (an atom)
ERROR: In:
ERROR:   [13] throw(error(type_error(dict,a),_13228))
ERROR:   [10] '<meta-call>'(user:user: ...) <foreign>
ERROR:    [9] toplevel_call(user:user: ...) at /usr/lib/swi-prolog/boot/toplevel.pl:1158
ERROR: 
ERROR: Note: some frames are missing due to last-call optimization.
ERROR: Re-run your program in debug mode (:- debug.) to get more detail.
```

Not sure how relevant this is practically but according to the literature this should be correct. Does SWI have a different predicate/procedure?

**Update**

The internal representation is also revealed by means of `display`:

```
?- display([1,2,3]).
'[|]'(1,'[|]'(2,'[|]'(3,[])))
```

Comment: Yes, see the SWI documentation at https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=ext-lists

Comment: not sure I get it ... does this mean that SWI's equivalent to `.(a,.(b,[]))` is `[a|[b|[]]]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As linked in the comments, the [SWI Prolog documentation](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=ext-lists) says:

> The ‘cons' operator for creating list cells has changed from the pretty atom `‘.’` to the ugly atom `‘[|]’`, so we can use the `‘.’` for other purposes, notably functional notation on dicts. See section 5.4.1.

That means the equivalent to your traditional `.(a,.(b,[]))` in SWI 7+ is:

```
?- X = '[|]'(a, '[|]'(b, [])).

X = [a, b]
```

Answer (score 1):

SWI prolog does not support `.` notation.
Instead a list with one element is denoted as `[A]` and a list with head H and tail T is denoted as `[H|T]`, e.g.

```
?- X = [1 | [2,3,4]]

X = [1,2,3,4]
```

Comment: this is just the usual prolog head/tail operation